# Unable to set windowState as Exclusive inside ActionClass in Struts2 Portlet

Tags: struts2, liferay-6, portlet

Issue: I am Unable to set windowState as Exclusive inside ActionClass in Struts2 Portlet, getting following exception: `"actionresponse cannot be obtained in render phase".`

Below is the code snippet inside my Action Class's method processRequest() method:

```
ActionResponse actionResponse = PortletActionContext.getActionResponse();// Exception occurs here!
actionResponse.setWindowState(LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE);
```

How can I make sure I obtain the actionResponse object and set the windowState to Exclusive as well inside my Action class.

Comment: There isn't action response in the render phase. You can get render response.

Comment: ya , that's correct but I cant set windowState in the renderResponse :(
how do I set windowState to exclusive inside my action class if the phase is Render only?

Comment: Make an action request and handle it in your java class.

Comment: @AleksandrM: I want to set windowState as Exclusive in <s:url />, so can I use the same as below: `<s:url var="billingOverview" action="%{OverviewURL}" windowState="<%= LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE.toString() %>" portletMode="view" portletUrlType="struts.portlet.action" />`

Comment: @AleksandrM: or I can simply say .. windowState="exclusive" ??

Comment: tried above didnt worked , I have now used below :
`<portlet:actionURL var="Overview"
 windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE.toString()%>">
 <portlet:param name="struts.portlet.action" value="%{OverviewURL}" />
</portlet:actionURL>`

but when I access `var="Overview"` inside <sj:tabbed/> panel it gives me "according to tld or attribute directive in tag file attribute name does not accept any expressions" exception

Comment: @AleksandrM: I am accessing `var="Overview"` as `<sj:tab href=${Overview}..../>` gave exception:""according to tld or attribute href, does not accept any expressions" , also tried `<sj:tab href=%{Overview}..../>` didnt gave any exception but it did not fetch any value either.. :(